# How to use Windows Authentication (Azure AD) in Flutter with Firebase

Tags: firebase, azure, flutter, firebase-authentication, windows-authentication

I am currently developing an app which requires windows authentication.
Access should only been given to users known in the azure active directory of the company.

I already:

- created an app registration with read access to azure.
- activated windows auth in my firebase project

There is some example code available on:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth?authuser=0
but it is not very well explained where I can get some of the used classes like 'OnSuccessListener' etc.

I would appreciate if someone can provide me some best practice code how to use the windows auth in flutter with firebase or also without firebase. Hopefully there is a possibility without storing the app registration secretly in the code.

In the end I need the usertoken to make api calls.

Answer (score 0):

Without Firebase you have the `msal_mobile [1]` package that will Authenticate with Azure AD on iOS and Android.

There's step-by-step instructions within the package for setting up within the Azure portal, along with the iOS and Android platforms. Then the Flutter code to sign-in is simply:

```
await msal.signIn(null, ["api://[app-registration-client-id]/user_impersonation"]).then((result) {
    print('access token: ${result.accessToken}');
})
```

Link
[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/msal_mobile

Answer (score 0):

There is now a way for you to sign in with Microsoft using Firebase Auth but at the time of writing, I haven't seen a way to use it in tandem with MS Graph. For those who don't need graph access, here's the method I used:

**Pubspec.yaml**

```dart
firebase_auth: ^0.18.3
firebase_core: ^0.5.2
```

**Your Widget**

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('login'),
          onPressed: () async {
            try {
              User user =
                await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow("microsoft.com", [
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All"
              ], {
                'tenant': '' //Your tenant ID here
              });
              print(user);
            } on PlatformException catch (error) {
              debugPrint("${error.code}: ${error.message}");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Assuming you've setup Firebase Auth and Azure App registrations properly, this should be enough for you to sign in via MS